# Read a XML file which is generated on a website and parse it with selenium

Tags: java, xml, dom, selenium, webdriver

I am testing a website which has a button and a text edit. On clicking the button a XML will  generate on the same page inside the text editor component. 
I want to read this XML which is generated and the parse it using the java DOM concepts

This is the html code for the text editor element. As we can see that the XML isn't specified here as any value. However the xml is specified as a DOM property under value property.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr id="textareafield-1241-inputRow">
<td id="textareafield-1241-labelCell" class="x-field-label-cell" width="105" valign="top" halign="left" style="display:none;">
<td id="textareafield-1241-bodyEl" class="x-form-item-body " role="presentation" colspan="3" style="width: 100%;">
<textarea id="textareafield-1241-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 100%; -moz-user-select: text; height: 173px;" placeholder="Provide XML" cols="20" rows="4" name="textareafield-1241-inputEl" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip=""></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Asking these type of question is not gonna fetch you an answer. Be specific on what you are asking ? Share us what you have and what you have tried.

Comment: So you are asking how to read the text from a text field with Selenium Webdriver. It doesn't seem that you've tried very hard. This is not well perceived on StackOverflow...

Answer (score 0):

Will be better if you provide an html code of text editor element.
In case of xml is present like a text in text editor you should simply getText() from this element.

```
WebElement textEditor = driver.findElement(By method);
String text = textEditor.getText();
```